# Error in your SQL syntax near ''

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a table with mySQL and it's throwing me the `Error in your SQL syntax` error and I can't figure out what is wrong with my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GalleryBase.Artist(
    Artist_ID_No int PRIMARY KEY,
    First_Name varchar(255),
    Last_Name varchar(255),
    Country varchar(255), 
    Style varchar(255),
    Alive CHAR(1), 
    Exhibition_Name varchar(255),  
    CONSTRAINT exhibition_fk FOREIGN KEY (Exhibition_Name) REFERENCES Exhibition(Exhibition_Name);
```

It says the error is on ln 9 at '' (two single quotes with no space between), which is the `CONSTRAINT` line, but if I delete that line, it says the error is on 8.

I'm not sure where this error near '' is.

Comment: missing parenthesis at end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not closed the parenthesis of `GalleryBase.Artist(`, put closing parenthesis at the end.

Comment: if that helped, can you accept this as the answer please, thereby helping me increase my reputation a bit ;) :p

Comment: Yup just waiting for the 10 minute timer

Answer (score 1):

Consider something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GalleryBase.Artist(
Artist_ID_No serial PRIMARY KEY,
First_Name varchar(255) not null,
Last_Name varchar(255) not null,
Country varchar(255) null, 
Alive tinyint null, 
Unique (first_name,last_name)
);
```

Exhibitions would not normally appear in this table.